# How do I force orbital movement around a point in space, while maintaining forward/backwards capability on a player?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

Long-winded question out of the way, I'll provide a diagram of what I am going for:

[image: Example]

The red square represents the character, the blue rectangle represents the camera, the green dot represents the center of the "stage", and the black circle is the stage itself.

What I desire is to essentially lock the player's movement around the "center" of the stage, so that anytime you move left or right you are more or less rotating around said center. However, I also want the player to be able to move forwards and backwards to/from the center as well. Keep in mind I want the camera to always stay directly behind the player. I have tried many different methods, and the latest is the following:

[image: Example2]

I took a default actor, attached a spring arm, attached a child actor to that (gets possessed to become the playable character), attached another spring arm, and finally the camera to that. I then added the blueprint code to the first spring arm so that it was the one being controlled by the left/right controls. However, upon hitting play, the only thing that moves is the camera, and it can only move forwards and backwards.

I'm admittedly pretty new to Unreal Blueprints, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Alright, I figured it out.

Here's the setup needed if anyone else wants something similar.

For the player themselves, you'll need something like this:

[image: Hierarchy]

The important thing is to center the root mesh where you want to rotate around. The spring arm's target arm length will be affected for the player mesh movement, giving the illusion you are physically moving the character. The second spring arm isn't necessary unless you wish to have more control over the camera to player distance.

For the rotation Blueprint, you'll need this:

[image: Rotation]

The target is whatever you named the root mesh. (Mine was called Center) Drag and drop it from the hierarchy.

For the forward/backward movement, you'll need this:

[image: Movement]

The target is what you named the spring arm. (I left mine as the default "SpringArm") Again, just drag and drop it from the hierarchy.

Adjustments in Project Settings:

[image: Engine Input]

Yes, my inputs are backwards from what you'd think. I felt it was quicker just to reverse the inputs instead of adjusting whatever was causing the movement to be backwards in the first place. (It's probably just the sphere orientation.) Also, you'll notice I have the w and s inputs set to 5 or -5 instead of 1 or -1. This is due to the fact the movement was slow otherwise. I'm sure there's a fix that doesn't involve changing the input axis scale, but honestly I won't really have a reason to alter the values at any point in my project. If it ever comes up where I do need to, I'm sure there's a bypass to change the values from within blueprints anyways.

End result:

[End Result Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn4nm2TruYs&feature=youtu.be)

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, child actor components are a bit different from other components in that they are transformation independent, that is they do not update their transformation when their parent component moves around.

I find it a bit strange that you would separate your player actor and the camera component. Normally, the player "pawn" contains the mesh and camera components for one player.

I would suggest you do the following:

- Create a player actor (e.g. a "pawn" or "character" class)
- Create the following component hierarchy:

  Root Scene -> Spring arm -> Skeletal or static mesh -> spring arm -> camera

Your root scene is the green center in your drawing. You can then basically use the blueprint you already have to rotate and move your player.

Comment: Ok, I just recreated the same scenario with a pawn instead of a base actor. The setup is as follows: Scene root>spring arm>static mesh>spring arm>camera.

Both spring arms are set to ignore camera clipping, as otherwise they won't offset the mesh and camera as they should. 

Initial free camera issue seems to be taken care of, but now no movement is occurring at all once "in game". I'd like to add that I've also tried switching the target in the blueprint to the default scene root and turning on/off inherit rotation values for the spring arms.